# how to show integer values in JComboBox?

Tags: java, jcombobox

I would like to know how to set a JComboBox that contain integers values that I could save.
Here is the definitions of values:

```
public class Item 
{
    private String itemDesc;
    private int itemType;

    public static int ENTREE=0;
    public static int MAIN_MEAL=1;
    public static int DESSERT=2;
    public static int DRINK=3;
    private float price;
    int[] itemTypeArray = { ENTREE, MAIN_MEAL, DESSERT, DRINK };
    Object[][] data = {{itemDesc, new Integer(itemType), new Float(price)}};
.
.
.
}
```

Now, I want the add a JComboBox that the user will choose 1 of the items (ENTREE, MAIN_MEAL...) and then I could set the number as an Integer.

I know that JComboBox need to be something like that:

```
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(itemTypeArray.values());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, combo,"Please Enter Item Type", `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want the numbers in the list or the names (ENTREE, MAIN_MEAL, ....)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor for JComboBox askes for `Object[]`. But you cannot convert an `int[]`-array to an `Integer[]`-array. So you have to change your list to

```
Integer[] itemTypeArray = { ENTREE, MAIN_MEAL, DESSERT, DRINK };
```

Then it is possible to construct the combobox:

```
Item t = new Item();
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(t.itemTypeArray);
```

But now you have the numbers in the list `(0, 1, 2, 3)`. So just make a `String`-array:

```
String[] itemAliasArray = {"Entree", "Main meal", "Dessert", "Drink"};
```

Now you can construct the combobox like this:

```
Item t = new Item();
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(t.itemAliasArray);
```

Now you have what you want (I think).

---

Notice that you are using a very strange design...

Answer (score 1):

Create Items as demonstrated in this [posting](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=57&threadID=613731)